# Issue with openpyxl.styles module in python, unable to set font attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, openpyxl

Having an issue using the openpyxl.styles.Font() function, I'm seeing it taught this way in the documentation as well, so unsure what might have changed.

```
>>> import openpyxl
>>> from openpyxl.styles import Font

>>> wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
>>> sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')

>>> font_style = Font(sz=30, i=True)

>>> sheet['A1'].font = font_style

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    sheet['A1'].font = font_style
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I've also tried it this way:

```
sheet['A1'].font = Font(size=30, italic=True)
sheet['A1'].font = Font(sz=30, i=True)
```

Getting this error message when I try to set a cell to a font style, nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Always use the documentation for the version of the software you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you use an old version of `openpyxl` because I can't reproduce your problem with the version v2.5.8.

Nevertheless, there is something curious: you are trying to get the "Sheet" worksheet from a newly-crated workbook. So this sheet doesn't exist.

You should try:

```
import openpyxl

from openpyxl.styles import Font

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.create_sheet('Sheet')
font_style = Font(sz=30, i=True)
sheet['A1'].font = font_style
```

This creates a new worksheet named "Sheet" and defines the font of the first cell.

Comment: That was it, I upgraded openpyxl and the problem is now resolved, thank you!